# Scala - Converting List[((String, String), Double)] to List[String,Map[String,Double]]

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've got a list of data that is of the structure `List[((String, Double), Double)]` where the columns are **Car Brand**, **Car ID** and **Average price**. I want to reformat this data into `List[String, Map[Int, Double]]`. I'm unsure where to begin.

I suspect that I'm supposed to use something like `.map(car => (car.brand, car.carColor, car.purchasePrice)` to split the values out, then another map to put them into the structure that I require.

The code to generate the data that I wish to reformat is as follows

```
val carStats = cars.groupBy(c => (c.brand,
     c.carID)).mapValues(cars => car.map(_.purchasePrice).sum / cars.length).toList
```

I ultimately want this list to be reformatted into `List[String, Map[String, Double]]`, but efforts so far haven't had much luck.

Comment: Can you share some example input and expected output? I believe you will have many **Car Brand** and many **Car ID** for each brand, and you want to group by both and compute the average price for each **Card brand** + **Car ID**. Also, can you please tell us which Scala version this has to be done. Finally, why `List[(String, Map[String, Double]]`? Wouldn't it be better a `Map[String, Map[String, Double]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are looking for ?

```
val result = carStats.map{case ((brand, id), avg_price) => (brand, id, avg_price)}.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(v => v.map{e => (e._2,e._3)}.toMap).toList
```

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks very much. I was struggling to get my head around this.